# Reshape 59x16 double into 236x4?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

How can I reshape a matrix in MATLAB, preferably using `reshape`?

A simple matrix setup:

```
A = [1 4 7 10; 2 5 8 11; 3 6 9 12]
```

that I want to reshape into

```
B = [1 4; 2 5; 3 6; 7 10; 8 11; 9 12]
```

I've tried numerous settings of `reshape`, but I cannot figure it out.

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

reshaped into

```
1 2
5 6
3 4
7 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the transformation properly it is:

```
A = [1 4 7 10; 2 5 8 11; 3 6 9 12]
B = A(:,1:end/2);
B = [B;A(:,end/2+1:end)];
```

Is this correct?

EDIT: 
Or the general case:

```
function [B] = elefaaant(A,n)
[a,b] = size(A);
if mod(b,n) ~= 0
    error('Cannot reshape')
end
B = zeros(a*n,b/n);
fac = b/n;
for i = 1:n
    B((i-1)*a+1:i*a,:) = A(:,(i-1)*fac+1:i*fac);
end
```

Comment: Yes this transforms my "short" example correct. But this doesn't work for the setup I have where I have a: number X 16 matrix, that I want to transform into a number X 4 matrix.

Comment: You can easily extend it by changing from using half of the columns to a quarter of the colunms at a time.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thx Nicky.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `reshape` and [permute](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
reshape(permute(reshape(A,size(A,1),2,[]),[1 3 2]),[],2)
```

Thanks to @LuisMendo that suggests a modification to the answer to avoid depending on the size of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
B = A(:,1:end/2);
B = [B;A(:,end/2+1:end)];

C = B(:,1:end/2);
C = [C;B(:,end/2+1:end)];
```

Maybe it can be done in a simpler way, but seems to work.

Comment: But this isn't the same as what you required, right? I picture the matrix as four "block" i.e. `[A B C D]` which you currently have stacked horizontally, but want vertically. Doesn't this code do `[A B; C D]` and then `[A;C;B;D]`, whereas your example would amount to `[A;B;C;D]`?

Comment: If I have [A B C D], what I want is to transform that into [A B; C D]

And if my matrix is bigger [A B C D E F G H; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8], then the function should transform it into [A B C D; 1 2 3 4; E F G H; 5 6 7 8]

Comment: What you describe is a single step through your code. What your code in the answer is doing is a double step, and that second step is different from what you a) describe in the answer and b) what the other answers, including the accepted one, do. Hence my comment, that your code does something different.